# NSViewController equivalent of the following UIViewController functions/variables?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to adapt the following [iOS Coreplot Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) for OSX, but am having trouble finding a few equivalent functions. To create a scatter plot, the tutorial is creating a class derived from UIViewController, but since I am on a Mac my equivalent of the class is derived from NSViewController.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; [1]
    [self initPlot];
}
```

In the above function, the class references a `[super viewDidAppear]`. NSViewController does not seem to have this function, therefore what function should I use instead?

```
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc]  
initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;    
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
```

In the above snippet, the class references a `self.view`. NSViewController does not have this function, there what equivalent function should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `-viewDidAppear:`. You may have to subclass `NSView` for your view controller's root view, and override `-viewWillMoveToSuperview:` and `-viewWillMoveToWindow:` to get similar behaviour. See the [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html) documentation for more information.

`NSViewController` has a `-view` method (`[self view]` instead of `self.view`, though you *can* use the latter syntax if you really want to.) Were you referring to something else?